# Interpreting Non-Parallel Pre-Treatment Trends in Difference-in-Difference Analysis: Coincidential Failure of Common Trend Assumption?

Tags: causality, difference-in-difference, identifiability

I'm conducting a Difference-in-Difference (DiD) analysis where I included clusters at the state level. To fulfill the crucial common trend assumption of DiD, I examined the pre-treatment period to see if there are parallel trends. I observed that the trends are not parallel.

However, I believe that the non-parallelism arises not from omitted variable bias but rather from coincidental developments at the state level. Given that my outcome variable is heavily influenced by state-level variables, this seems to be a plausible explanation.

My question is: Do these coincidental developments invalidate the common trend assumption and lead to biased results? Alternatively, does this non-parallelism just imply that there is a decrease in the precision of the estimate?